# Codeigniter ob_flush() only works in Controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, popen

My code **ob_flush** only works inside my controller.

**This is my code:**
test_controller1.php

```
public function test()
    {
        $var    = "/bin/test";

        $result = popen($var , 'r'); 
            $start = false;
            while($line = fgets($result, 2048))
            {
                echo "<pre>".$line."</pre>";
                ob_flush();flush(); 
            } 
        pclose($var);

    }
}
```

Using the code above works fine. It outputs the result while the script is still running. Which is my intended output.

However, what I want is to put this code inside my view.

**Example Controller:**
test_controller2.php

```
public function test()
    {
            $data['var']    = "/bin/test";
            $this->load->view('test_view', $data);
    }
}
```

**Example View:** 
test_view.php

```
$result = popen($var , 'r'); 
    $start = false;
    while($line = fgets($result, 2048))
    {
        echo "<pre>".$line."</pre>";
        ob_flush();flush(); 
    } 
pclose($var);
```

Using the code above works, but it will wait for the script to finish before showing the results.

In summary, I want to output the results while the script is still running using the controller with the view(test_controller2.php)

Comment: i think what you are experiencing is just the nature of how CI parses the view. not sure if anything can be done about it, but i doubt it

Comment: Hi @Alex , oh i see thanks.  so I guess I'll just have to do it in my controller